# Three.js load a gltf model and set color for it but when zooming out it is all black

Tags: vue.js, web, three.js, gltf

Hello everyone，I have meet a strange problem which is that I loaded a gltf model in three.js and set color for it.When zooming in it has colors, but when zooming out,it is all black.And when I directly set color for it's material,it can works well.
Thank you.

here is the sample sreenphotos and code.
[image]
[image]
[image]

```
loadGlbModel() {
  const loader = new GLTFLoader();
  loader.load(
    `/three/eiffel-tower.gltf`,
    (gltf) => {
      const geometry = gltf.scene.children[0].geometry;
      const positions = geometry.attributes.position;
      const count = positions.count;
      geometry.setAttribute(
        "color",
        new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Float32Array(count * 3), 3)
      );
      const color = new THREE.Color();
      const colors = geometry.attributes.color;

      const radius = 200;
      debugger;
      for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        color.setHSL(positions.getY(i) / radius / 2, 1.0, 0.5);
        colors.setXYZ(i, 1, 0, 0);
      }

      const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        color: 0xffffff,
        flatShading: true,
        vertexColors: true,
        shininess: 0,
      });

      const wireframeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        color: 0x000000,
        wireframe: true,
        transparent: true,
      });

      let mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
      let wireframe = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, wireframeMaterial);
      mesh.add(wireframe);
      mesh.scale.set(0.1, 0.1, 0.1);
      const redColor = new THREE.Color(1, 0, 0);
      console.log(mesh);
      // mesh.children[0].material.color = redColor;
      const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
      light.position.set(0, 0, 1);
      this.scene.add(light);
      this.scene.add(mesh);
    },
    (xhr) => {
      console.log((xhr.loaded / xhr.total) * 100 + "% loaded");
    },
    (error) => {
      console.error(error);
    }
  );
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are rendering the wireframe version too, which consists of lines in screen-space. As you zoom out, these lines maintain the same width in pixels, thus covering everything else.

Do you wish to render the fireframe too? If not, don't. If you do, then consider hiding it as the user zooms out.

Comment: Thank you very much.I remove the wireframe from my code as you say and it works well.